# converting bytestream to RGB using libjpeg

Tags: rgb, libjpeg

I intercept a packet and extract the payload. This payload is compressed jpeg bytestream data (for example this data is assigned to `unsigned char *payload`). I know that if I have a FILE pointer, then I can use libjpeg library to extract image information. My question is there a way to pass my pointer(`*payload`) to the libjpeg functions to get the RGB values and the dimension of the image?

Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

Re: Adam Rosenfield's answer, you don't have to implement anything yourself: `jpeg_mem_src()` will do what you want:

```
jpeg_mem_src(&cinfo, payload, payload_len);
```

You must have the entire image stored in memory (and know its length).

obStackoverflow: I know, an answer to a really old question, but today I have to do just this and this page was the first or second ranked in response to my web search.

Comment: I wasn't able to get this to work in `raw_data_out` mode. Kept getting `Improper call to JPEG library in state 205`. As far as I can tell, if you are going to call `jpeg_read_raw_data()`, you must populate the function pointer members of a `jpeg_source_mgr` struct you assign to your `src` member.

Answer (score 3):

To add to [Tal's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/832864/converting-bytestream-to-rgb-using-libjpeg/832919#832919), what you should do is take a look at the implementation of the `jpeg_stdio_src()` function in `jdatasrc.c`.  The purpose of that function is to initialize the data source object, namely `cinfo->src`.  So, what you should do is the following:

1. Create a structure (similar to the `my_source_mgr` structure in `jdatasrc.c`) which has as its first member an instance of `struct jpeg_source_mgr`.  Add any other members that you feel are necessary.  Note that we're essentially doing manual inheritance -- in C++, we would define a class that derives from `jpeg_source_mgr`, and the various function pointers declared in `jpeg_source_mgr` would instead be virtual functions.  But, we're using C, so we have to do inheritance and polymorphism the hard way.
2. Allocate space for an instance of your structure, making sure to allocate the right number of bytes, and fill out your data members.
3. Implement the following five functions:

   - `void init_source(j_decompress_ptr)`
   - `boolean fill_input_buffer(j_decompress_ptr)`
   - `void skip_input_data(j_decompress_ptr, long)`
   - `boolean resync_to_start(j_decompress_ptr, int)`
   - `void term_source(j_decompress_ptr)`

   Note that for an in-memory buffer, these functions will probably be very trivial.
4. Finally, initialize the function pointers in your `jpeg_source_mgr` member to point to those functions.

With this in place, you can then use this instead of `jpeg_stdio_src()` to initialize the data source manager, and then you should be good to go as if you were decoding a file from the file system.

Answer (score 0):

libjpeg has input/output managers that can be extended to use raw memory buffers or any other form of I/O you have, but AFAIK only FILE* is actually implemented in the library's release.

Answer (score 0):

In recent builds of libjpeg `jpeg_mem_src` is already implemented for you.

It is very easy to compile libjpeg for windows.

Download the [source from the project webpage](http://www.ijg.org/)
Extract everything in a single folder
Then [open a Visual Studio 10 command prompt](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229859.aspx) to that directory

Type

```
nmake /f makefile.vc setup-v10
```

This will create a .sln file which will open in VS2010. It should compile from there.

You may also debug libjpeg source afterwards.

Comment: When I open VS comand prompt it gives an error, that it couldn't locate the VS Common Toosl folder so it doesn't recognizes the nmake command, is there any fix for these?

Comment: Just locate nmake and call it directly. Like >C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\bin\nmake /f makefile.vc setup-v10